# What test are running during deployment?

Tags: apex

when a package is deployed what test are fired? For example, in sfdc I have class1 and test1 and in my package I have a new version of this code (class1.2 and test1.2). What test are fired? Test1, test1.2 or both?

Answer (score 0):

During a package deployment all the test classes with latest revisions are executed.So, in this example during deployment SF will execute the new version of the test class **"Test1.2"** along with the other existing test classes in the org.

Comment: This answer is correct in this specific case. It gets a little more complicated when you're working with an actual org. I'd suggest trying to find documentation to corroborate and expand your answer.